# How to use array_push to add value and key to array

Tags: php, array-push

I am receiving an error once this code runs. I have looked up possible solutions but everything seems to be formatted correctly.

```
$searched = 'searched';    
$count    = '59';
$prop     = Array();

$i = 0;
while ($i++ <= 4) {
    array_push($prop[$i] = Array(
         'text' => $searched,
         'href' => 'http://mysite.com/?search=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $searched)
    ));
}

array_push($prop['Total Searches'] = $count);
```

I receive this error 5 times for the while loop, and 1 time for the array_push under the while loop.

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for array_push()
```

The code works correctly! but it still calls out the error. So should I just suppress the error?

Comment: I altered your formatting a bit to make it vaguely legible. Next time, please go ahead and do that yourself!

Comment: -1 for considering "just suppress[ing] the error". +1 for realising that it might not be a good idea, and asking about it. :)

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure out how the back ticks worked. Im going to create an account here since I received an answer so swiftly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
array_push($prop['Total Searches'] = $count);
```

to:

```
$prop['Total Searches'] = $count;
```

etc.

You only use array_push to push a value on to the end of a list-style array.  This is not relevant here, as you're just setting a new key/value pair.

Comment: Thank you! I have been starring down this code for almost an hour.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please click the checkmark outline next to this answer if you are happy with it.  That will indicate the question is answered and help other people find the favorite answer.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Done! I tried clicking it as soon as i ran the code, but I had to wait 11 mins :/ Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing approaches.

Read about [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), which doesn't do what you think it does.

`array_push($array, $val)` is like `$array[] = $val`.

You want *just*:

```
$prop[$i] = Array(
     'text' => $searched,
     'href' => 'http://mysite.com/?search=' . str_replace(' ', '+', $searched)
));
```

and

```
$prop['Total Searches'] = $count;
```

Comment: +1 - dkamins has it right as well, but this is a better answer in my opinion

Comment: Thanks, from what dkamins said i was able to remove the array_push from the while loop as you described.

Comment: @Eric: It's more thorough, but it's certainly not one of my most comprehensible answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

this will do your job,

```
$searched = 'searched';    
$count    = '59';
$prop     = Array();
$search_terms = Array();

$i = 0;
while ($i <= 4) 
{
   $search_terms['text'] = $searched;
   $searched = str_replace(' ', '+', $searched);
   $search_terms['href'] = 'http://mysite.com/?search='.$searched;
   array_push($prop, $search_terms);
   $i++;
}

$prop['Total Searches'] = $count;
```

and check [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), thats what i am using.